# Android status bar won't hide

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble hiding the status bar.

If I use this code to enter full immersive mode (hide statusbar and navigation) it DOES hide the navigation but the statusbar just keeps sitting there:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Neither works. Also tried the manifest approach without the setSystemUiVis() function (just to test if it would work - which it should because I've used this before) but it doesn't.

Testing on Android 4.4.2 (Sony z2 tablet) and Android L Dev preview (second release, Nexus7)

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Somehow Cordova (2.7.0) was interfering with the fullscreen stuff.

To get it to work, first edit config.xml in (res/xml/config.xml) and add the following preference:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Then, in the onWindowFocusChanged method, comment this line:

```
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
```

So it should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
         //   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }
}
```

Last but not least: DO NOT use a .Fullscreen theme in your manifest.

Whoop.